# ***Time limit exceeded*** error on python program

Tags: python

when i try to print this line:
print(perfect_square(0))
i should get True but instead i get a time limit exceeded error and i dont know how to fix it.

i tried chaging it to an elif statment instead of 2 separate if statements but i still get that error

This is my current code:

```
def perfect_square(n):
    s = 1

    while s != n:
        if s*s == n:
            return True
        elif s == 0:
            return True
        else:
             s +=1
        
    return False



def perfect_cube(n):
    s = 1

    while s != n:
        if s*s * s == n:
            return True
        elif s == 0:
            return True
        else:
             s +=1
        
    return False
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your program (either in your head, or on paper, or in a debugger) and it'll be pretty obvious what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Seems quite clear to me why the `perfect_square(0)` and `perfect_cube(0)` cases cause an infinite loop. You start `s=1` and always increment it `s+=1`. It will never be equal to `n=0` so you get an infinitely running program. Maybe try making checks for invalid values of `n`?

```py
def perfect_cube(n):
    if n < 1: return False
    # ...
```